# Javascript FOR Loop Callback

Tags: javascript, loops, callback

There's a list of items IDs `gameIds[i]_container` that are displayed in a `FOR` loop.  On These are being displayed without a problem.

I want the console to log the item's `gameIds[i]` on that items click.  I believe this is supposed to be accomplished with a callback, but currently nothing occurs when items are clicked on.

Please help!

**Code:**

```
//CLICKING ON GAMES
//Active Game - bring user to game
//Newly Invited Game - ask user to accept invite, then either bring to game or delete from players list
//Rematch Game - recreate previous game

//Function
function gameAccess(i) {
    //REMATCH GAME
        if (currentRound[i] == roundWinners[i].length && currentRound[i] != 0 && currentRound[i] == numberOfRounds[i]){
            console.log("You clicked " + gameIds[i]);
        }
        //NEWLY INVITED GAME
        if (currentRound[i] == 0 && currentUserId != creator[i]) {
            console.log("You clicked " + gameIds[i]);
        }
        //ACTIVE GAME
        else{
            console.log("You clicked " + gameIds[i]);
        }
}

//Callback
function gameAccessCallback(i){
    return function(){
        gameAccess(i);
    };
}

//Iterate Through
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    document.getElementById(gameIds[i] + "_container ").click(gameAccessCallback(i));
};
```

Comment: Your question mentions `gameIds[i]_container`, but that is not valid Javascript.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623088/undefined-indexes-in-array-after-asynchronous-requests/8623120#8623120 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880895/why-when-i-add-a-bunch-of-event-listeners-in-a-loop-does-every-element-trigger/18880964#18880964 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487187/why-is-the-loop-assigning-a-reference-of-the-last-index-element-to/21487254#21487254 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273839/proper-code-for-a-for-loop-in-javascript/22273973#22273973

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate.  His `gameAccessCallback` function solves the problem in those duplicates.  He's just not binding the event properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are doing `document.getElementById(...).click()`.  DOMElements don't have a `click` method!  jQuery does, but it doesn't look like you are using that here.

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    document.getElementById(gameIds[i] + "_container ").addEventListener('click', gameAccessCallback(i));
}
```